# Aviary + Wordpress Media

Tags: images, media

has anyone tried to implement Aviary API and wordpress successfully? I am looking for a tutorial or guide of some sort.

Comment: Please add more details: What exactly do you want to do? What have you tried already (show us some code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just Finished a part of my theme framework which Integrates aviary editor to WordPress media library and since i was asked, I released it in a plugin form [Aviary Editor](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/aviary-editor/)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Awesome bro, we actually implemented it on our upload as well, but we will install this as well, our editors needs it. Awesome work

Comment: If you like to share the code I'll add it to the plugin

Comment: Our website is using user uploaded images and they can edit them using aviary. We are using AJAX for it. When the user edits, we retrieve the file from aviarys servers and replace the file while creating all the corresponded thumbnails. You can see how it works on our website www.bangstyle.com, create an account, upload a picture and go to profile and edit it. I can share the code if needed.